# How to replace newline followed by space in Parsley PEG grammar

Tags: python, parsing, peg

all 
I'm learning Parsley by writing parser that parse vCard format. My problem is that some lines in vCard format may be split over several lines. Multiple-line representation using the RFC 822 “folding” technique. That is, wherever there may be linear white space a CRLF immediately followed by at least one LWSP-char.
My solution is first parse raw text, there I can find newline followed by space and join that lines. However I can't get it to work: there is my latest try:
The code returns errors there is last:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'bool' and 'str

```
import parsley
my_newline = "\n"
space = " "

def isLogicalLine(txt=""): #Function called from Parsley, just search for newline followed by space
    result = True
    if txt[:-2] == my_newline+space:
        result = False
    return result

tst_line2 = parsley.makeGrammar("""
CRLF = '\n' 
line = (~(CRLF) anything+:x ?(isLogicalLine(x))):first_part  -> first_part+ ' test '
""", {"isLogicalLine":isLogicalLine})
# ~(CRLF) = NOT CRLF
# ?(isLogicalLine(x)) = python expression that is true or false
# -> first_part+ ' test ' == modify result by Python express

test_string = "BEGIN:VCARD"+my_newline+"VERSION:2.1"+my_newline+\
              "N;CHARSET=UTF-8;ENCODING=8BIT:Bab"+my_newline+\
              "TEL;PREF;VOICE;ENCODING=8BIT:123456789"+my_newline+"END:VCARD"+\
              my_newline+" END:VCARD"

print(tst_line2(test_string).line())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by moving the test out of the binding, like so:

```
line = (~(CRLF) anything+:x):first_part ?(isLogicalLine(x)) -> first_part + ' test '
```

Not sure if it's a bug or not, but `first_part` was being bound to the result of the `isLogicalLine` test, so `first_part + ' test '` was trying to add a bool and a string.